# get current week moday javascript

Tags: javascript, datetime, momentjs

i want to get current week 'Monday'  based on today's time,  samples are:

21-11-2017 output should be 20-11-2017

23-11-2017 output should be 20-11-2017

26-11-2017 output should be 20-11-2017

```
var d = new Date();
 console.log(d.getDate())
 console.log(d.getDay()+1)
d.setDate(d.getDate() - d.getDay()+1);
```

the code is working fine except for sunday (26-11-2017) manaully changed time to test different cases it returns

```
Mon Nov 27 2017 23:50:39 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time)
```

for other dates like

25-11-2017 it return  Mon Nov 20 2017 23:50:39 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time)

24-11-2017 it return  Mon Nov 20 2017 23:50:39 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time)

22-11-2017 it return  Mon Nov 20 2017 23:50:39 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time) 
that is desired but **for EVERY sunday it returns the upcoming monday** i couldn't figure out something good

In short i want to start my week from monday not from sunday

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `setDate` rather than `setDay` to change the date in the instance. Loop until you get to Monday:

```js
var dt = new Date();
while (dt.getDay() != 1) {
  dt.setDate(dt.getDate() - 1);
}
console.log(dt.toString());
```

Example with your starting dates:

```js
test("19-11-2017");
test("20-11-2017");
test("21-11-2017");
test("22-11-2017");
test("23-11-2017");
test("24-11-2017");
test("25-11-2017");
test("26-11-2017");
function findMonday(dt) {
  while (dt.getDay() != 1) {
    dt.setDate(dt.getDate() - 1);
  }
  return dt;
}
function test(str) {
  var parts = str.split("-");
  var dt = findMonday(new Date(+parts[2], +parts[1] - 1, +parts[0]));
  console.log("Start: " + str + ", found: " + dt.toString());
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Or it's **slightly** more efficient (nothing that's going to matter unless you're doing this hundreds of thousands of times in a tight loop) to figure out how many days back to go and go all at once:

```js
var dt = new Date();
var days = ((dt.getDay() + 7) - 1) % 7;
dt.setDate(dt.getDate() - days);
console.log(dt.toString());
```

Example with your starting dates:

```js
test("19-11-2017");
test("20-11-2017");
test("21-11-2017");
test("22-11-2017");
test("23-11-2017");
test("24-11-2017");
test("25-11-2017");
test("26-11-2017");
function findMonday(dt) {
    var days = ((dt.getDay() + 7) - 1) % 7;
    dt.setDate(dt.getDate() - days);
  return dt;
}
function test(str) {
  var parts = str.split("-");
  var dt = findMonday(new Date(+parts[2], +parts[1] - 1, +parts[0]));
  console.log("Start: " + str + ", found: " + dt.toString());
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```