# How can I retrieve current week's data on Mongoose?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I have a Model for all requests that I get for my business (real estate).

I want to create an aggregation middleware based on the "createdAt" field which returns only models created between monday at midnight and  the present time.

I have looked through all previous questions but could not find anything and the aggregation docs in mongo are so huge I cannot wrap my head around!

Do you have any tips?

I have tried this but it's returning an empty array:

```
getGestionaleStats = async (req, res) => {
try {
    const richieste = await Richiesta.aggregate([
        {
            $match: {
                createdAt: { $lt: new Date() }
            }
        },
        {
            $group: {
                _id: { $week: '$createdAt' }
            }
        }
    ]);

    res.status(200).json({
        status: 'success',
        data: { richieste }
    });
} catch (err) {
    console.error(err.message);
    res.status(500).json({
        status: 'error',
        data: err.message
    });
}
```

Of course the `{$lt: new Date()}` is probably where the problem lies.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

This solution uses Aggregation query and a custom JavaScript function. The function takes a date object and returns the first Monday's date before today. This is used to get all the documents with `createdAt` date after *the calculated date*.

```
// Function returns the date of the "last Monday" from
// the given input date.
function getLastMonday(dt) {

    let n = null; // last Monday conversion

    switch (dt.getDay()) {
        case 0: n = -5; break;
        case 1: n = -6; break;
        case 2: n = 0; break;
        case 3: n = -1; break;
        case 4: n = -2; break;
        case 5: n = -3; break;
        case 6: n = -4; break;
        default: "This never happens";
    }

    let today_date = new Date(dt.getFullYear(), dt.getMonth(), dt.getDate());
    let last_monday_date = today_date.setDate(today_date.getDate() + n );

    return last_monday_date;
}

var d = ISODate();    // -or- any date like ISODate("2019-11-26T00:00:00Z")
var LAST_MONDAY = getLastMonday(d);

db.test.aggregate( [
{ 
  $addFields: { 
      last_monday: { 
          $dateFromParts : {
              year: { $year: new Date(LAST_MONDAY) }, 
              month: { $month: new Date(LAST_MONDAY) }, 
              day: { $dayOfMonth: new Date(LAST_MONDAY) }
           }
      },
      created_at: { 
          $dateFromParts : {
               year: { $year: "$createdAt" }, 
               month: { $month: "$createdAt" }, 
               day: { $dayOfMonth: "$createdAt" }
           }
       }
  } 
},
{ 
  $match: { $expr: { $gt: [ "$created_at", "$last_monday" ] } }
},
{ 
  $project: { created_at: 0, last_monday: 0 } 
}
] )
```

For a set of input documents like this:

```
{ _id : 1, createdAt : ISODate("2019-12-03T00:00:00Z") }
{ _id : 2, createdAt : ISODate("2019-11-12T02:00:00Z") }
{ _id : 3, createdAt : ISODate("2019-11-25T05:00:00Z") }
{ _id : 4, createdAt : ISODate("2019-11-26T00:00:00Z") }
{ _id : 9, createdAt : ISODate("2019-12-02T23:45:00Z") }
```

And, `LAST_MONDAY = getLastMonday(ISODate("2019-12-04T05:40:20Z"))`, the aggregation query returns the document with `_id : 1`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using momentJS for this:

```
const result = Collection.aggregate([
  { 
    $match: {
      createdAt: { 
        $gte: moment().startOf('isoweek').toDate(),
        $lt: moment().endOf('isoweek').toDate()
      },
    }
  }
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found an answer with vanillaJS:

```
const richieste = await Richiesta.aggregate([
            {
                $match: {
                    createdAt: { $gte: getBeginningOfTheWeek(new Date()), $lt: new Date() }
                }
            },
            {
                $group: {
                    _id: null,
                    count: { $sum: 1 }
                }
            },
]}
```

where `getBeginningOfTheWeek` is as such:

```
exports.getBeginningOfTheWeek = (now) => {
    const days = (now.getDay() + 7 - 1) % 7;
    now.setDate(now.getDate() - days);
    now.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
    return now;
};
```

The latter function is from T.J. Crowder: [get current week moday javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47420784/get-current-week-moday-javascript/47420815#comment104572248_47420815)